# What greeting should I use when asking question

Tags: support

This may sound a little silly, but I am having problems opening up my questions with a greeting. I am not a native speaker and frankly - I don't know a lot of ways how to politely present a question. I usually try to start it with something like "Hello" or "Hi", but the system keeps deleting it for some reason. And starting a question without it seems rude to me.

So what is a generally accepted way to open up a question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is generally agreed that questions should *not* have a greeting.

Comment: Ok then, I just don't want it to seem rude.

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič, if you browse through the list of questions, you'll see that that is the local custom. I assure you that that will not make you seem rude.

Comment: One reason for this custom is that the first $n$ words of each question show up in the list of questions. We want that to be as informative as possible/